# react native windows, spawn npm ENOENT error

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, react-native

I am trying to run react-native on windows and get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files>react-native init AwesomeProject
```

> This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in
>   C:\Program Fil es\AwesomeProject Installing react-native package from
>   npm... events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: spawn npm ENOENT
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:860:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
>       at doNTCallback2 (node.js:450:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:364:17)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:459:11)
>       at startup (node.js:136:18)
>       at node.js:972:3

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does the path `C:\Program Files\AwesomeProject` exist and if not can your current user create it with their set of permissions?

Comment: @tkone, yes it does. It has 1 file `package.json` with the following code there `{"name":"AwesomeProject","version":"0.0.1","private":true,"scripts":{"start":"node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"}}`

Comment: is there anymore to your error message? ENOENT means that its trying to access a directory/file that doesn't exist. Can you change the log level on the command?

Comment: So apparently this was fixed in react-native 0.1.9 in windows as long as you don't use the `--verbose` feature in your `init` call, ref: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

react-native-cli@0.1.8 error

Rollback react-native-cli@0.1.7

everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this could communicate a lot better if you used `text` instead of an image and full sentences.

Answer (score 9):

This should be fixed in React Native CLI 0.1.9. To update your CLI:

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

There was a regression in 0.1.8, reported here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5169

Comment: This is the clearest answer I've seen to the issue, and solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

Check if the **gradlew.bat** file is present in the **android folder** if it is not there then simply copy **gradlew.bat** file from another project.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to solve the issue if there is no other projects at hand?

Comment: @OlegKurbatov you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44860306/what-is-gradle-wrapper-and-gradlew-bat-file) for more info

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, **Reinstall** **NodeJS** https://nodejs.org/en/

[image]

**Then**

```
npm install -g react-native-cli --vebrose
react-native init App --verbose
```

[image]

If it still fails, try installing **Python 3** https://www.python.org/ and repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `gradlew.bat` & `gradlew` file from this path `project/android/` and copy that files from another react native project & paste this into thi path `project/android/` then run npm install & run the project.